# Python sendto and recvfrom methods consuming much time in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I'm working on a program that can send files and messages from a Client to a Server. For sending files through the network I am using UDP (the program is for a school assignment and I can not use TCP). I have also created a header on top of UDP, that have different attributes. All of the attributes are converted to bytes before I send them.

```
def encode_to_send(type, checksum, packet_number, data):
    # data -> str
    # type -> char
    # packet_number -> int
    # checksum -> int
    if data is None:
        data = ""
    type_bytes = bytes(type, "iso-8859-2")
    checksum_bytes = checksum.to_bytes(4, "big")
    packet_number_bytes = packet_number.to_bytes(4, "big")
    if isinstance(data, str):
        data_bytes = bytes(data, "iso-8859-2")
    else:
        data_bytes = data
    byte_all = type_bytes+checksum_bytes+packet_number_bytes+data_bytes
    return byte_all
```

Here's an example of the call:

```
data_to_send = encode_to_send(type, checksum, packet_number, msg)
s.sendto(data_to_send, (server_address, server_port))
```

The problem is that when I send these bytes, the built in method `sendto()` and the servers response `recvfrom()` takes too much time.

My colleagues are also working on this assignment and for them these methods are being executed much faster than for me. As I am using `PyCharm`, I also tried running the profiler to see the time consumption for these methods and my colleagues also sent me their profiler for comparison.

What could cause this behavior for these methods?

Snips of the pstat files:

Pstat file for my program
[image: Pstat file for my program]

Pstat file for my colleague's program
[image: Pstat file for my program]

Methods above the `sendto()` and `recvfrom()` are calling these builtins or they are input fields, which explain why they consume so much time.

I am using Python 3.9.7 and my colleague is running 3.9.5. I am using Windows operating system, however this program was also tested on Linux on a different PC. The behavior of these methods were the same.

Comment: Is the server and client on same machine ? Or you have a network in place ?

Comment: I've tried it on the same machine (just using Windows), in a local network (Linux VM and Windows) and just Linux VM. I've tried it with loopback address and local network address too.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out what the problem was. I had multithreading implemented, which had a `while` loop, which was constantly checking if a `threading.Event` was set or not. I found out, that my CPU was constantly switching between these threads and that caused slowdowns. The solution was to send for a small amount of time that thread with the while loop `sleep`, so that my main thread could send the file faster.